# Access Properties File(other than MessageResources files) using Struts1 tag

Tags: struts-1, resourcebundle

I am using Struts1.x. I have already configure MessageResources parameter in struts.xml and I am able to access it via struts tld "bean".

As I said I have already configured in my struts.xml:

```
<message-resources parameter="ApplicationResource" />
```

Is there any way to add one more resource property file in that,
or any other alternative?

I don't want to use the following code:

```
<%
ResourceBundle rb =  ResourceBundle.getBundle("sg4pigweb");
String enviromentInfo = rb.getString("sg4p.ig.site.name");
%>
```

Please help me.

How to do it using tags (either Struts1.x or jsp) & what is recommended to use?

Comment: You can already specify multiple bundles and access them by key, e.g., http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/userGuide/configuration.html#a5.2.2_Message_Resources_Configuration.

Comment: Is it possible to add more than one Message Resources like 
<message-resources parameter="ApplicationResource" />                                  <message-resources parameter="AppSggpResource" /> ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. The solution is as follows:
you add in struts-config.xml the new message resource definition:

`<message-resources parameter="MessageResources"/>
<message-resources parameter="MessageResourcesNew" key="new"/>`

Note: When you define multiple message resource bundles, you must assign a key to all but one. The one you don't assign a key to will be the default bundle

Then you access it with the new key value. Or you can read it from Java using:

`MessageResources mres = MessageResources.getMessageResources("MessageResources")`